# Solve $\log_2x= \log_4(x+6)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve $\log_2x= \log_4(x+6)$  for $x$ using the change of base formula.

I already tried changing the base on both sides but that didn't work I know it must be in the form of a quadratic for a substitution to be made.

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: its perfect thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

From the [change of basis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) you have $ \log_2 x=2\log_4 x=\log_4 x^2$

and
$$
\log_4 x^2=\log_4 (x+6) 
$$
in $\mathbb{R}$, iff

$$
x^2=(x+6) \quad \land \quad x+6>0 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Assume: $$\log_2x=y$$
then
$$x=2^y=(4^{1/2})^y=4^{y/2}$$

which means
$$\log_4 x=y/2$$

Answer (score 0):

or you can write $$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}=\frac{\ln(x+6)}{2\ln(2)}$$
i think this will help you

Comment: this looks a little reasonable but im still confused

Comment: this gives $$2\ln(x)=\ln(x+6)$$ or $$\ln(x^2)=\ln(x+6)$$

Comment: further help will be appreciated